# Asymptotic behaviour of the function $f(x) = \frac {k}{(a^2 + x^2)^{ {3}/{2}}}\vec e_x$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics

I got a function $f(x) = \frac {k}{(a^2 + x^2)^{ {3}/{2}}}\vec e_x$, where $\vec e_x$ is an unit vector in the $x$ direction and $k$ is a constant. And I should study the asymptotic behaviour of this function for $x \to +\infty$ and $x \to -\infty$.

I tried to graph this function and I didn't find any critic points and I calculated this limit as $0$. So I don't understand what to do, If I missed something important.

The function corresponds to the magnetic induction and this example is from an old test, so I don't have solution and I am curious.

I have searched that asymptotic analysis and do I understand right that I need to find a function that this function relates to for really large x? This part of math/physics is new to me, so that is why I was confused that the limit is just $0$ and I did not find a other counterexample to understand that.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: The function corresponds to the magnetic induction and this example is from an old test, so I don't have solution and I am curious.

Comment: No more information. But it seems like this function doesn't have any asymptotic behaviour.

Comment: Have you looked up "asymptotic"? You should find one of the top hits to be [asymptotic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis). Where did you find this problem?

Comment: I have searched that asymptotic analysis and do I understand right that I need to find a function that this function relates to for really large x? This part of math/physics is new to me, so that is why I was confused that the limit is just 0 and I did not find a other counterexample to understand that.

Comment: I have added a bit more detail regarding the asymptotic series to my answer.

Comment: I have also taken the liberty of adding some of your comments to your question to enhance the context in your question. I hope that is okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Taylor series for $(1+x)^{-3/2}$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{k}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^{3/2}}
&=k|x|^{-3}\left(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)^{-3/2}\\
&=k|x|^{-3}-\frac{3ka^2}2|x|^{-5}+\frac{15ka^4}8|x|^{-7}+O\!\left(|x|^{-9}\right)
\end{align}
$$
So asymptotically, to the first order, we have
$$
\frac{k}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^{3/2}}\sim k|x|^{-3}
$$
This means that
$$
\lim_{|x|\to\infty}\frac{\frac{k}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^{3/2}}}{k|x|^{-3}}=1
$$
For higher order of approximation, we have the asymptotic series
$$
\frac{k}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^{3/2}}\sim\frac{k}{|x|^3}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(2j+1)\binom{2j}{j}\left(-\frac{a^2}{4x^2}\right)^j
$$
Unlike most asymptotic series, the series above actually converges for $|x|\gt|a|$.

Comment: Just a little question: Taking $x$ as a complex number is a nonsense, right?

Comment: And thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @Leif: One could consider $x$ to be a complex variable, but there was nothing to suggest one do so. As stated, it seemed that $x$ was real. More care would need to be taken about branch cuts if we are to consider $x$ as complex.